# i can't pull data by column name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I just started working with the pandas library. Despite my research, I still haven't figured it out.
I want to pull the data for the column named q. But it gives an error. How can I do that?

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df.loc[df['q']])
```

Error:

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "c:/Users/sabca/visual studio code projects/webscraping/pandastest.py", line 11, 
            in <module>
                print(df.loc[df['q']])
            File "C:\Users\sabca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
            packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 879, in __getitem__        
                return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
            File "C:\Users\sabca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
            packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1099, in _getitem_axis     
                return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
            File "C:\Users\sabca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
            packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1037, in _getitem_iterable
                keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis, raise_missing=False)
            File "C:\Users\sabca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
            packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1254, in _get_listlike_indexer
                self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis, raise_missing=raise_missing)
            File "C:\Users\sabca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site- 
            packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1298, in _validate_read_indexer
                raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
            KeyError: "None of [Index(['qwe1', 'asdf1', 'adfs4', 'wer7', 'tyu1', 'ghfhg5'], 
            dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: `df.loc[df['q']]` does not look right.. Looks like you need just `df.loc['q']` or `df['q']`

Comment: This is quite basic. After you read from excel sheet, you already have a dataframe to work with. you just have to access the column that you need from it `data['q']`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Fixing the `data`/`df` confusion**

Firstly, there's really no need for the line

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

As `data` is already a Pandas DataFrame as returned by the `pd.read_excel` function.

Instead I would suggest ommiting this line and going simply with the following (I will be using `df` to refer to the Pandas DataFrame generated using this function for the remainder of this answer).

```py
df = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx')
```

**Returning a Pandas Series from column `q`**

Assuming that `q` is the name of a column in your `df` then:

```py
df['q']
```

Will return a Pandas Series representing the column `q`.

If you wanted to use `df.loc` this indexing method takes a range of rows to be returned as the first item and an optional range of columns as the second. Assuming you are seeking to return all rows of the column `q` you could use.

```py
df.loc[:, 'q']
```

**Returning a Numpy array of values from column `q`**

You could use:

```py
df['q'].values
```

To return a Numpy array containing the values stored within the `q` column.

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to use indexing and `loc()`. Try just:

```py
df.loc[:, 'q']
```

This gets all rows (`:`) for the specified column (`q`).

Comment: should be **data**, as per the code of OP `data` is already a dataframe

Comment: Appears OP has both `data` and `df`, so either should be appropriate, but `df` is more widely used (and it's the one OP is referencing in their indexing).

Comment: I agree, but it would be educational to point out the mistake.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone for your help. You have given me many different perspectives. thank you for everything

Answer (score 1):

You can just apply `.values` property. It will return a numpy array of the values in the pandas column. Like `df['q'].values`. So import Numpy to work with it.

Another is `df['q']` to return pandas series of column q.

I would not use `df.loc` for hard syntax, still you can try `df.loc[:, 'q']` and don't index instead slice in `df.loc`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use:

```
print(df['q'])
```